# Understanding fixed-point notation in GCC/Clang

Tags: c, gcc, clang, fixed-point

I am trying to wrap my head around how the fixed-point notation works. I have read the documentation from https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n996.pdf but still cannot quite grab it.

Here is an example from Clang's unit tests:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/test/Frontend/fixed_point_div_const.c

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/test/Frontend/fixed_point_div.c

A small snippet looks like this:

```
// Division between different fixed point types
short _Accum sa_const = 1.0hk / 2.0hk;
```

How should I think of these division operators? Are they where the decimal point is? If so, is there a way I can visually verify that binary representation (i.e. by printing out the values) somehow?

Comment: This looks very much like C-code, doesn't it?

Comment: Definitely c, not c++, see the gcc manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Fixed-Point.html. Prety sure your example isn't doing anything fancy, its just setting `sa_const` to `0.5`

Comment: Re “If so, is there a way I can visually verify that binary representation (i.e. by printing out the values) somehow?”: To see the representation of any object in C, convert its address to `unsigned char *` and use that to print its bytes in any way you desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How should I think of these division operators?

You should think of these divisions as unit tests to check that division works.

There's probably more unit tests somewhere (e.g. doing things like `short _Accum sa_const2 = 0.5hr * 2.0hk;` to test that multiplication works, and `short _Accum sa_const2 = 0.5hr + 2.0hk;` to check that addition works, and...).

> Are they where the decimal point is?

No. The decimal point is determined by the variable's type. E.g. a `short _Accum` is described as (at least - see note) "s4.7" which means it has 1 sign bit, 4 integer bits and 7 fractional bits; and `short _Accum myValue = 3.5hr` would be equivalent to `short myValue = (3.5) * (1 << 7);`.

*Note: Just like how C originally got normal variable types wrong/implementation dependent (e.g. so nobody can be sure if `int` is 16 bits or larger, and portable software written/tested on larger computers breaks due to bugs on smaller computers) which is a problem they "corrected" with the introduction of better types later (e.g. `int_least16_t`); they've repeated the same mistake by making fixed point types equally wrong/implementation dependent.*

Of course this (the position of the decimal point determined by the variable's type) is also what makes the proposed/draft fixed point support "likely unusable for it's intended purpose". Specifically; people that care are also likely to care about getting the best range and precision compromise; which means they need the result of each operator to (potentially) be a different fixed point type - e.g. like "s4.7 + s4.7 = s5.6" (because addition/subtraction causes you to need 1 more bit to avoid overflow) and like "s4.7 * s4.7 = s8.3"; and like "(s4.7 + s4.7) * s4.7 = s5.6 * s4.7 = s9.2" (or maybe "s5.6 * s4.7 = s9.10" if you want to use more bits to preserve precision).

> is there a way I can visually verify that binary representation (i.e. by printing out the values) somehow?

I'm guessing you can cast it to a raw unsigned integer type and print that.

Comment: You aroused my curiosity. Where does the quote "likely unusable for its intended purpose" come from?

Comment: @rici: That's just my attempt at avoiding a less polite and much shorter phrase. ;-)